# Emmet wrap with abbreviation - keeping empty lines VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

this may be a silly ask but wondering if it is possible.

Say I have 3 paragraphs

[image: 3 paragraphs]

and I would like to wrap them in P tags. I use `p*` and that will wrap the paragraphs but it removes the space between them

[image: them]

Is there a way to keep that space between the paragraphs so it looks like

[image: this]

But only for elements being wrapped with P tags.

Thank you for any suggestions.